# A strange grammar in C++ not operator==

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm reading/compiling an open source package Trilinos. The source code could be found on Github. I found the following strange grammar that leads to a compiling error with the Intel compiler (Windows) while gcc 4.9.x in Ubuntu works.

```
bool Slice::operator!=(const Slice & slice) const
{
  return (not operator==(slice));
}
```

The error messages are:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       identifier "not" is undefined   domi    .\packages\domi\src\Domi_Slice.hpp  475
```

Question:
1> What does the above grammar mean?
2> Is this C++ standard? Why does the Intel compiler not support the grammar?

Comment: Alternative operators: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: Online Intel likes it (check your compilation switches): https://godbolt.org/g/L2dmUw

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. Not sure what to add to make compiler support this feature. I'm looking for the compiler's instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Intel compiler is emulating older VC++ versions which, as an *extension* (really!), have these [alternate operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) disabled.

You can get them back again by including the [`<iso646.h>` header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn494964.aspx).

Or just use `!` instead of `not`.

Answer (score 0):

`not` is just a simple negation (like `!=`
Used word `operator` means defining a meaning of operator you see after word `operator` - read about overloading the operator in C++.

Comment: Operator is a usual grammar, but "iso464" is really not that common. Thanks for your kind explanation.